# How to display a specific value from another google sheet to create dashboard

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In sheet 1, column D, each row has a certain set of values in a dropdown; i.e., pending approval, approved, finished.

In sheet 2, i would like to display the values from sheet 1, column, but only if they are 'pending approval'

essentially, i only want to display rows that are still pending approval. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

its either:

```
=FILTER('sheet 1'!A:C; 'sheet 1'!D:D="approved")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_of_your_sheet 1_here; "sheet 1!A:D"); 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 
  where Col4 = 'approved'")
```